# How to remove exception 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, ios10

I'm learning iOS development from an older version of a book. I used an Empty Template & I'm getting a runtime error in 'main.m' although the code seems fine there:

```
return UIApplicatio Main(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I imported "HypnoView.h" objective C class in AppDelegate.m
In AppDelegate.m I added this code in '- (BOOL)applicarion:.....' :

```
CGRect firstFrame = CGRectMake(160,240,100,150);
HypnoView *firstView = [[HypnoView alloc] initWithFrame:firstFrame];
firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.window addSubview:firstView];
```

Book does mention I'll will get this exception as a warning or comment. But i'm getting a runtime error.

Comment: The code (at least the last line anyway) you have posted is many years out of date. Please find an up-to-date tutorial/book.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wil get the up to date edition.